# nginx apt packaging conflict

Tags: unix, nginx, package, apt

I'm having a problem install nginx-extras because it seems like it depends on nginx-common version 1.1.19-1ubuntu0.2, but I'm installing in addition (1.4.1-1ppa1~precise). I need that 1.4.1 version because I need some of the new changes made to the nginx source.

When I run `apt-cache show nginx-common` I get:

```
Package: nginx-common
Source: nginx
Version: 1.4.1-1ppa1~precise
Architecture: all
Maintainer: Kartik Mistry <kartik@debian.org>
Installed-Size: 210
Depends: lsb-base (>= 3.2-14)
Suggests: nginx-doc, fcgiwrap
Breaks: nginx (<< 0.8.54-4), nginx-extras (<< 0.8.54-4), nginx-full (<< 0.8.54-4), nginx-light (<< 0.8.54-4)
Replaces: nginx (<< 0.8.54-4), nginx-extras (<< 0.8.54-4), nginx-full (<< 0.8.54-4), nginx-light (<< 0.8.54-4)
Homepage: http://nginx.net
Priority: optional
Section: httpd
Filename: pool/main/n/nginx/nginx-common_1.4.1-1ppa1~precise_all.deb
Size: 77152
SHA256: fc513f97505ec4c37a819d8638386b142f395619bbb1b2e1a6f96c71e45ba77c
SHA1: 2893621a5d8d7a625f3e584e92df41410d48e3bd
MD5sum: 09ba7fdaf059d6ba96a24fd5cdb686bb
Description: small, powerful, scalable web/proxy server - common files
 Nginx ("engine X") is a high-performance web and reverse proxy server
 created by Igor Sysoev. It can be used both as a standalone web server
 and as a proxy to reduce the load on back-end HTTP or mail servers.
 .
 This package contains base configuration files used by all versions of
 nginx.

Package: nginx-common
Priority: optional
Section: universe/httpd
Installed-Size: 200
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Kartik Mistry <kartik@debian.org>
Architecture: all
Source: nginx
Version: 1.1.19-1ubuntu0.2
Replaces: nginx (<< 0.8.54-4), nginx-extras (<< 0.8.54-4), nginx-full (<< 0.8.54-4), nginx-light (<< 0.8.54-4)
Depends: lsb-base (>= 3.2-14)
Breaks: nginx (<< 0.8.54-4), nginx-extras (<< 0.8.54-4), nginx-full (<< 0.8.54-4), nginx-light (<< 0.8.54-4)
Filename: pool/universe/n/nginx/nginx-common_1.1.19-1ubuntu0.2_all.deb
Size: 17478
MD5sum: e9f62c39292ae12072e955b3c53c36ff
SHA1: bafdca3b4ddb3a36f2a8ac701f99ac9c3c03ab11
SHA256: 7fc493c9e624b652890b66e8dc250b175a7c33219063e6faeb6131f4d765c20e
Description-en: small, but very powerful and efficient web server (common files)
 Nginx (engine x) is a web server created by Igor Sysoev and kindly provided to
 the open-source community. This server can be used as standalone HTTP server
 and as a reverse proxy server before some Apache or another big server to
 reduce load to backend servers by many concurrent HTTP-sessions.
 .
 This package contains base configuration files used across multiple packaged
 versions of Nginx (nginx-full, nginx-light, nginx-extras, nginx-naxsi).
Homepage: http://nginx.net
Description-md5: 46d30b3e77cd81636fb13d66df5209bc
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu

Package: nginx-common
Priority: optional
Section: universe/httpd
Installed-Size: 200
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Kartik Mistry <kartik@debian.org>
Architecture: all
Source: nginx
Version: 1.1.19-1
Replaces: nginx (<< 0.8.54-4), nginx-extras (<< 0.8.54-4), nginx-full (<< 0.8.54-4), nginx-light (<< 0.8.54-4)
Depends: lsb-base (>= 3.2-14)
Breaks: nginx (<< 0.8.54-4), nginx-extras (<< 0.8.54-4), nginx-full (<< 0.8.54-4), nginx-light (<< 0.8.54-4)
Filename: pool/universe/n/nginx/nginx-common_1.1.19-1_all.deb
Size: 17756
MD5sum: 4d250e4ce04c0632149d26c0870ad2c8
SHA1: 360a48743d26977c4b87122e68e1a980526b7048
SHA256: c90436744a72726e29b7373b082434caec3942b87e2362053631de06ed665c4a
Description-en: small, but very powerful and efficient web server (common files)
 Nginx (engine x) is a web server created by Igor Sysoev and kindly provided to
 the open-source community. This server can be used as standalone HTTP server
 and as a reverse proxy server before some Apache or another big server to
 reduce load to backend servers by many concurrent HTTP-sessions.
 .
 This package contains base configuration files used across multiple packaged
 versions of Nginx (nginx-full, nginx-light, nginx-extras, nginx-naxsi).
Homepage: http://nginx.net
Description-md5: 46d30b3e77cd81636fb13d66df5209bc
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
```

As you can see there are multiple versions of nginx installed. So if the nginx-extras packages depend on 1.1.19-1ubuntu0.2, and I have that installed, why is it still throwing this error. Do I need to specify a version of the nginx-extras that works with my version of nginx? How would I go about figuring out what version that would be?

I can provide more information if needed. Thanks! In the "Breaks" part of the output it reports the nginx-extras it breaks, do I just pick a package that is newer than that?

Comment: BTW: workaround (if you don't need multiple versions).

1. Backup conf, cert and www files etc.
2. `sudo apt purge nginx-*`
3. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable`
4. `sudo apt update`
5. `sudo apt install nginx-extras`. The goood thing about extras: Lua support.